# MacOS UI Tests Destination on Xcode9 server?

Tags: xcode-server

I have reasonable good experiences with Xcode9 server, developing for the Mac. It seems to work, even my unit-test suite is running. However, I struggle with UI tests. My test run out of the IDE, but not in the server, giving me the message:

> No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were
>   valid for the specified scheme 'UI Tests'.

I tried to add -destination 'platform=OS X,arch=x86_64' to the "arguments passed to xcodebuild" section of the bot, but that seems to be ignored.

I believe that this is somehow related to the fact that UI tests have a defined target. But who knows how to fix it?

Comment: Why does this have the "coded-ui-tests" tag? It is specific to Microsoft's Visual Studio.

Comment: Only MS VS has coded UI Tests?

Comment: Yes, read the information about the tag. (Hover the mouse pointer over the tag.)